# Trying to create game objects aligned in screen responsively UNITY

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am trying to create game objects in the screen aligned from the center, they are just characters ordered from the center to the sides, i am pretty bad explaining things so i will just attach an image

[image: http://i.imgur.com/rPXOmw4.png]

Comment: You need to post more info (unfortunately). Do you want to do that by script? Did you already try anything? Are your objects images or text?

Comment: are you familiar with UNity's superb UI system?  https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/user-interface-ui  Start learning it - it contains a superb reactive layout system, which will do this for you.

Comment: Hey!; i want to do it by script, i can't use unity UI now :( 
they must be gameobject independent from the UI.